# Is k-d tree suited for keeping triangles or i need some changes in classic k-d tree building algo?

Tags: computational-geometry, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I've read k-d tree description in wiki, wiki says that k-d tree keep points. I have mesh of triangles and need some structure for effective calculation intersections with cylinder and distance to point queries. As I understand, if I split my mesh by the plane - many triangles can intersect that plane. So what shoud I do? Put copies of triangles in left and right child boxes, or split intersected triangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split intersected triangles. Take a look at any open-source Ray-Tracing algorithms which use KD-Trees for how to do this, or search for academic papers on Google Scholar.

Take a look at the Surface Area Heuristic for a good way to choose splitting planes, it is generally used in Ray Tracing but it may be applicable in your situation.

Comment: I've already implemented 3d kd-tree with triangles. If splitting plane intersects triangle i put it in both child nodes. I use SAH and min-max binning for choosing splitting plane -it's good compromise between construction speed and quality of the tree for me. After your answer i've started thinking about idea of splitting triangles. What's the pros and cons of splitting\non splitting triangles particularly for NNS and range queries in you opinion?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. My reason for splitting them is that you can then use a standard KD-Tree with bounding boxes for speed in NN lookups. If you don't split triangles then the bounding boxes grow a bunch, reducing the efficiency of the NN search.